# How to get data for a Button title from XML in monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I am making an app in which user can change language. I am thinking about making an xml file for each supporting language and then tell app to load an xml on basis of user selected language. For example i have and xml file called English.xml like following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <English>
    <string name="LoginButtonText">Login</string>
 </English>
```

How can i get this LoginButtonText string to use it as my Button title.
I am using Xamarin. Any idea how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not wanting to use the standard strings.xml resource method that most Android apps follow (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) you can do the following:

Load your xml document like so (you may have to set the build action for the file to "content"):

```
var stringsDoc = XDocument.Load ("English.xml");
```

To get the appropriate string from the XML:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> strings =
    (from el in stringsDoc.Root.Elements("string")
    where (string) el.Attribute("name") == nameToLookFor
    select el);

var buttonLabel = strings.First ().Value;
```

In your activity, you set the title of the button like so:

```
Button myButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
myButton.Text = buttonLabel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in the layout which will make the language dynamically load from the string file according to the language selected

android:text="@string/LoginButtonText"

You should use separate string file to localize. So, for that I had attached links below for you

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_5_-_application_localization_and_string_resources/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/localization/

for your reference I use to make it like this
English: values ->strings.xml
Telugu: values-te ->strings.xml